# Which is more efficient to use on a mobile platform SVM or Neural Networks ?

Tags: android, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, neural-network, svm

I'm currently working on a framework for emotions and I'm planing on using input from a camera on a mobile platform to recognize the user's current emotional expression, using the [CI2CV](http://face.ci2cv.net) i managed to extract 66 landmarks, using those 66 landmarks I should be able to Classify the expression to one of 8 pre defined basic emotions in the form of probabilities such as: happy=81% , angry=9% ... etc

which is more effective for this purpose? using SVM or Neural Networks, baring in mind that this must be done on a mobile platform so resource consumption and limitation is a concern.

Comment: Such question has definite answer, without "opinions", so the closing votes seems to be casted by non-experts in the field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it was previously stated, only the actual classification should be performed on your mobile device. So, in terms of **classification time** of trained model:
If you construct the linear model than both SVM and Neural Network will be **equally fast**. If you, however use non linear transformation, than SVM can be considerably slower, if it chooses to many support vectors. SVM with N suport vector is more or less as fast as NN with N hidden neurons

Comment: I would appriciate the comment of -1 vote, especially if someone disagrees with this (quite trivial) observation.

Answer (score 3):

Certainly you don't have to (and shouldn't) do the training/cross-validation/validation on the mobile device. That's what will take the most time.

Once you have your classifiers trained, then simply running a set of features through them (you'll likely end up with 1 classifier per emotion) shouldn't take too long with either SVM or a Neural Net.

Comment: is there a noticeable lag between the two? or a certain preference that would give one an edge over the other ?

Comment: The best way to determine that is to implement both and use a profiler to determine the performance characteristics..

Comment: Thank you , that was a very good insight